# Draw Chart which axis interval is non-sequential in C#

Tags: c#, charts

It`s simple that draw a sequential interval.

If I draw like below chart, which C# component I use?
Or can I setting for draw like this on ms-chart control?

[image: chart]
<sub>(source: [tistory.com](http://cfile30.uf.tistory.com/image/2176034052A8345530B338))</sub>

Comment: Do you want to create a logarithmic scale?

Comment: Exatly what I want is draw grid line like that. I can draw like that by typing. If there is other way, I want to know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Chart chart1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chart1 = new Chart();

        var chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
        chartArea1.AxisX.IsLogarithmic = true;
        chartArea1.AxisX.Maximum = 1000D;
        chartArea1.AxisX.Minimum = 1D;
        chartArea1.AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
        chartArea1.AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;

        var series1 = new Series();
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0D, 0D));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10D, 10D));
        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(100D, 100D));
        chart1.Series.Add(series1);

        chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
        chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 300);

        Controls.Add(this.chart1);
    }
```

Comment: Oh Thanks! I see mschart provides log value.