# Improving VB.NET Chart Label Values

Tags: graphics, charts, vb.net-2010, mschart

It works out that when using the autofit of axis labels, the label values take on unappealing values.   Has anyone developed code to evaluate range and scale of axis values and then show for example label values at intervals of 1, 5, 10, 20, etc? The syntax I am using is listed below:

```
                Chart1.Series.Clear()
                Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
                Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
                Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "N2"
                Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "N2"
                Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.LabelStyle.Angle = 0
                Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = True
                Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = True
                Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 12.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
                Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 12.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
                Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = True
```

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED: I discovered that if you use the floor and ceiling functions on xmin and xmax, and set intervalautomode=True, then the last right label will typically be displayed, and the labels will appear better.  The floor and ceiling prevent label values of -2.3, 5.7, etc.

```
    Dim xmin, xmax As Double
    xmin = 1.0E+30
    xmax = -1.0E+30
    For i = 1 To 1000
        If x(i) < xmin Then xmin = x(i)
        If x(i) > xmax Then xmax = x(i)
    Next
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = Math.Floor(xmin)
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = Math.Ceiling(xmax)
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = True
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "N1"
    For i = 1 To 1000
        Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(x(i), y(i))
    Next
```

You would need to do more work if the range of x is less than 1, for example 0.02 to 0.85, or 0.0002 to 0.005, etc. since the floor and ceiling always round down to the next lower integer and round right to the next greatest integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `AxisX.Minimum` and `AxisX.Interval`.

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.FixedCount
```

You can set `AxisX.Minimum` according to `Series.Points(0).XValue` if you want.

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = Math.Floor(Chart1.Series(0).Points(0).XValue / 5) * 5
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 5
```

Comment: My thinking was to first determine the range $\Delta= x_{max}-x_{min}$ and then determine how many times $10^x$ goes into the $\Delta$, where $x=10^{-4},10^{-3},10^{-2},10^{-1},10^{0},10^{1},10^{2},10^{3}$ etc. and then determine label intervals of 0.2, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, etc., which look the most appealing.

Comment: Please check out [draw-chart-which-axis-interval-is-non-sequential-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515734/draw-chart-which-axis-interval-is-non-sequential-in-c-sharp/20536243#20536243)

Comment: Thanks- that's a nice log-linear chart with a grid.

Comment: The syntax below fixed it:         Dim xmin, xmax As Double
        xmin = 1.0E+30
        xmax = -1.0E+30
        For i = 1 To 1000
            If x(i) < xmin Then xmin = x(i)
            If x(i) > xmax Then xmax = x(i)
        Next
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = Math.Floor(xmin)
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = Math.Ceiling(xmax)
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = True
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "N1"